# Having trouble understanding append/prepend for my javascript project

Tags: javascript, jquery, project, resume

```js
name = "Joel Carter";
title = "Software Developer"
mobile = "708-5xx-xx90"
email = "carter3689@gmail.com"

var formattedName = HTMLheaderName.replace("%data%", name);
var formattedTitle = HTMLheaderRole.replace("%data%", title);
var formatedMobile = HTMLmobile.replace("%data%",mobile);
var formattedEmail = HTMLemail.replace("%data%", email);
var formatted

$("#header").append(formattedName);
$("#header").append(formattedTitle);
$("#topContacts").prepend(formatedMobile);
$("#topContacts").prepend(formattedEmail);
```

```css
body,
div,
ul,
li,
p,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.clear-fix {
  overflow: auto;
}

.education-entry,
.work-entry,
.project-entry {
  padding: 0 5%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #f5a623;
  line-height: 48px;
  display: inline;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #999;
  line-height: 29px;
  padding: 10px;
}

h3 {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 22px;
}

h4 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #4a4a4a;
  line-height: 17px;
}

h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  padding:10px 5%;

}


.date-text {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #999;
  line-height: 16px;
  float: left;
}

.location-text {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #999;
  line-height: 16px;
  float: right;

}

p {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 21px;
}

a {
  color: #1199c3;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.welcome-message {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #f3f3f3;
  line-height: 28px;
}

#skills-h3 {
  color: #f5ae23;
  display: none;
}

.orange {
  background-color: #f5ae23;
}

.orange-text {
  color: #f5ae23;
}

.white-text {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.gray {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  clear:both;
}

.dark-gray {
  background-color: #4a4a4a;
}

/* TODO: Replace with image later */
#header {
  background-color: #484848;
}

.flex-box {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 10px;
}

.center-content {
  padding: 2.5% 5%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.biopic {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  display: none;
}

img {
  padding: 10px;
}

span {
  padding: 5px;
}

#lets-connect {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Media queries to handle various device widths */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #lets-connect {
    margin-top: 5%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:900px) {
  .biopic {
    width: 175px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  #lets-connect {
    margin-top: 10%;
  }
  .biopic {
    width: 150px;
  }
  .welcome-message {
    display: none;
  }
}

#map {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 5%;
}

#mapDiv {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 750px) {
  #skills-h3,
  .biopic {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--
This is an HTML document. It contains information about how elements in the website
are arranged. In other words, it describes the layout of a website.

I can't wait to see the resumes you put together!

Cameron Pittman, Udacity Course Developer
-->

<!--
The <head> of a website generally links to important resources the page will
need to load. You'll see a lot of <link>s to CSS files for styles and
<scripts> for JavaScript files to build interactions.
-->
<head>
  <!-- This tells the browser how to read the document. -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <!-- Tells the browser what the title of this page should be. -->
  <title>Resume</title>

  <!-- Load the page styles. -->
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--
  jQuery is a common JavaScript library for reading and making changes to the
  Document Object Model (DOM). The DOM is a tree that contains information
  about what is actually visible on a website.

  While HTML is a static document, the browser converts HTML to the
  DOM and the DOM can change. In fact, JavaScript's power comes from
  its ability to manipulate the DOM, which is essentially a JavaScript
  object. When JavaScript makes something interesting happen on a
  website, it's likely the action happened because JavaScript changed
  the DOM. jQuery is fast and easy to use, but it doesn't do anything
  you can't accomplish with vanilla (regular) JavaScript.
  -->
  <script src="js/jQuery.js"></script>

  <!-- More on helper.js in the class -->
  <script src="js/helper.js"></script>

  <!--
  Uncomment the <script> tag below when you're ready to add an interactive
  Google Map to your resume!
  -->
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script> -->

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main">
      <!-- You'll be deleting this line in the course -->

    <!--
    Everything from here to the <script> tag below is the skeleton of your
    website. Your code will add information to each of the sections of the
    resume below. You can pretty easily figure out what each section will
    display by looking at the id or at what's written between the <h2> tags.
    -->
    <div id="header" class="center-content clear-fix">
      <ul id="topContacts" class="flex-box"></ul>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div id="workExperience" class="gray">
      <h2>Work Experience</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="projects">
      <h2>Projects</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="education" class="gray">
      <h2>Education</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="mapDiv">
      <h2>Where I've Lived and Worked</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="lets-connect" class="dark-gray">
      <h2 class="orange center-text">Let's Connect</h2>
        <ul id="footerContacts" class="flex-box">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--
  The next line tells the browser where to download the JavaScript file you'll be
  writing. In resumeBuilder.js, you'll be writing code that builds the resume
  dynamically when this website, index.html, is opened.
  -->
  <script src="js/resumeBuilder.js"></script>


  <!--
  These scripts are written in JavaScript. You'll be breaking them down as part of
  a quiz. Essentially, the next few lines are checking to see if you have not
  changed each section of the resume. If you have not made any changes to a section
  of the resume, then that part of the resume does not show up. More on this in the
  course.
  -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Notice how all of a sudden there's JavaScript inside this HTML
    // document? You can write JavaScript between <script> tags. At the end of your
    // JavaScript, don't forget the closing script tag with the slash (/).


    // Also, this is a JavaScript style comment. You can comment in JavaScript with:

    //   two slashes for all following characters on a single line, or

    /*
        an opening and closing set of slash asterisks for block comments.
    */


    if(document.getElementsByClassName('flex-item').length === 0) {
      document.getElementById('topContacts').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(document.getElementsByTagName('h1').length === 0) {
      document.getElementById('header').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(document.getElementsByClassName('work-entry').length === 0) {
      document.getElementById('workExperience').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(document.getElementsByClassName('project-entry').length === 0) {
      document.getElementById('projects').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(document.getElementsByClassName('education-entry').length === 0) {
      document.getElementById('education').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(document.getElementsByClassName('flex-item').length === 0) {
      document.getElementById('lets-connect').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(document.getElementById('map') === null) {
      document.getElementById('mapDiv').style.display = 'none';
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am currently working on a Udacity nanodegree project where I need to create a resume dynamically using JS. I was moving pretty good until I ran into this current wall and would love help climbing over if anyone could assist.

I am trying to append contact information under my name but the elements keep showing up on top of my name.

Here's the current state of the code:

```
name = "Joel Carter";
title = "Software Developer"
mobile = "708-5xx-xx90"
email = "carter3689@gmail.com"

var formattedName = HTMLheaderName.replace("%data%", name);
var formattedTitle = HTMLheaderRole.replace("%data%", title);
var formatedMobile = HTMLmobile.replace("%data%",mobile);
var formattedEmail = HTMLemail.replace("%data%", email);

$("#header").append(formattedName);
$("#header").append(formattedTitle);
$("#topContacts").prepend(formatedMobile);
$("#topContacts").prepend(formattedEmail);
```

Here is the HTML as well (almost for got this part)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--
This is an HTML document. It contains information about how elements in the website
are arranged. In other words, it describes the layout of a website.

I can't wait to see the resumes you put together!

Cameron Pittman, Udacity Course Developer
-->

<!--
The <head> of a website generally links to important resources the page will
need to load. You'll see a lot of <link>s to CSS files for styles and
<scripts> for JavaScript files to build interactions.
-->
<head>
  <!-- This tells the browser how to read the document. -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <!-- Tells the browser what the title of this page should be. -->
  <title>Resume</title>

  <!-- Load the page styles. -->
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--
  jQuery is a common JavaScript library for reading and making changes to the
  Document Object Model (DOM). The DOM is a tree that contains information
  about what is actually visible on a website.

  While HTML is a static document, the browser converts HTML to the
  DOM and the DOM can change. In fact, JavaScript's power comes from
  its ability to manipulate the DOM, which is essentially a JavaScript
  object. When JavaScript makes something interesting happen on a
  website, it's likely the action happened because JavaScript changed
  the DOM. jQuery is fast and easy to use, but it doesn't do anything
  you can't accomplish with vanilla (regular) JavaScript.
  -->
  <script src="js/jQuery.js"></script>

  <!-- More on helper.js in the class -->
  <script src="js/helper.js"></script>

  <!--
  Uncomment the <script> tag below when you're ready to add an interactive
  Google Map to your resume!
  -->
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script> -->

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main">
      <!-- You'll be deleting this line in the course -->

    <!--
    Everything from here to the <script> tag below is the skeleton of your
    website. Your code will add information to each of the sections of the
    resume below. You can pretty easily figure out what each section will
    display by looking at the id or at what's written between the <h2> tags.
    -->
    <div id="header" class="center-content clear-fix">
      <ul id="topContacts" class="flex-box"></ul>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div id="workExperience" class="gray">
      <h2>Work Experience</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="projects">
      <h2>Projects</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="education" class="gray">
      <h2>Education</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="mapDiv">
      <h2>Where I've Lived and Worked</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="lets-connect" class="dark-gray">
      <h2 class="orange center-text">Let's Connect</h2>
        <ul id="footerContacts" class="flex-box">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--
  The next line tells the browser where to download the JavaScript file you'll be
  writing. In resumeBuilder.js, you'll be writing code that builds the resume
  dynamically when this website, index.html, is opened.
  -->
  <script src="js/resumeBuilder.js"></script>


  <!--
  These scripts are written in JavaScript. You'll be breaking them down as part of
  a quiz. Essentially, the next few lines are checking to see if you have not
  changed each section of the resume. If you have not made any changes to a section
  of the resume, then that part of the resume does not show up. More on this in the
  course.
  -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Notice how all of a sudden there's JavaScript inside this HTML
    // document? You can write JavaScript between <script> tags. At the end of your
    // JavaScript, don't forget the closing script tag with the slash (/).


    // Also, this is a JavaScript style comment. You can comment in JavaScript with:

    //   two slashes for all following characters on a single line, or

    /*
        an opening and closing set of slash asterisks for block comments.
    */


    if(document.getElementsByClassName('flex-item').length === 0) {
      document.getElementById('topContacts').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(document.getElementsByTagName('h1').length === 0) {
      document.getElementById('header').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(document.getElementsByClassName('work-entry').length === 0) {
      document.getElementById('workExperience').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(document.getElementsByClassName('project-entry').length === 0) {
      document.getElementById('projects').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(document.getElementsByClassName('education-entry').length === 0) {
      document.getElementById('education').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(document.getElementsByClassName('flex-item').length === 0) {
      document.getElementById('lets-connect').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(document.getElementById('map') === null) {
      document.getElementById('mapDiv').style.display = 'none';
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, here is a screenshot of the trouble I am having:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you also supply the html document and any css files.

Comment: do you want `$("#header").append(formatedMobile);` ?

Comment: `prepend`, add before, *(pre)*, and `append`, add after etc.

Comment: can you show the source of the generated page?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that the div #header already contains the ul element #topContacts.  So anything you .append() will be placed after this element. Instead of .append() I would try .before();

```
$('#topContacts').before(formattedName + formattedTitle);
```

This will insert your name and title before the ul elment. And then for the un-ordered list #topContacts try:

```
$('#topContacts').append($('<li>').html(formattedMobile)); 
$('#topContacts').append($('<li>').html(formattedEmail));
```

This will add an li element inside the ul element that contains the text for your mobile and email info.